# Get domain name from an email address

Tags: c#, email, domain-name

I have an email address

```
xyz@yahoo.com
```

I want to get the domain name from the email address. Can I achieve this with Regex?

Comment: if in doubt (or you haven't tried anything) use a RegEx! Now you have two problems.

Answer (score 140):

Using [MailAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailaddress.aspx) you can fetch the `Host` from a property instead

```
MailAddress address = new MailAddress("xyz@yahoo.com");
string host = address.Host; // host contains yahoo.com
```

Answer (score 29):

If [Default's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18980269/) is not what you're attempting you could always `Split` the email string after the `'@'`

```
string s = "xyz@yahoo.com";
string[] words = s.Split('@');
```

`words[0]` would be `xyz` if you needed it in future
`words[1]` would be `yahoo.com`

But Default's answer is certainly an easier way of approaching this.

Comment: Just as a heads up, email addresses can contain multiple "@". I'm pretty sure the last one will always separate the "user" from the "domain" though.

Answer (score 10):

Or for string based solutions:

```
string address = "xyz@yahoo.com";
string host;

// using Split
host = address.Split('@')[1];

// using Split with maximum number of substrings (more explicit)
host = address.Split(new char[] { '@' }, 2)[1];

// using Substring/IndexOf
host = address.Substring(address.IndexOf('@') + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple Substring Method will do the trick here

string emailAddress = @"myemail@gmail.com";
string domainName = emailAddress.Substring(emailAddress.IndexOf('.',emailAddress.LastIndexOf('@')));

Console.WriteLine (domainName);

Or If you have have bit of money you can get this library and that will do the work for you

https://afterlogic.com/mailbee-net/docs/MailBee.Mime.EmailAddress.GetDomain.html

Comment: I would add that, while MailBee.NET Objects is indeed a commercial product, some namespaces like MIME or HTML can be used at no cost.